# Not receiving GCM push notification from Amazon SNS

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am trying to send **Push notification** to **android** app through **php**. 
I setup **amazon sns** account and created **SNS Platform** using **Google Server key for GCM API**.

Using **AWS credentials**, i wrote a **cron** which reads notification message from database and publishes to sns service using amazon php api.
I am getting Amazon endpoint in cron on which i publish notification.

I am receiving status as **pass** and a **requestid** for notification. But actual notification is not receiving on device.

```
Array ( [data] => Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object ( [structure:protected] => [data:protected] => Array ( [MessageId] => ac9e1d0c-43a4-5d1a-833d-50c94465421d [ResponseMetadata] => Array ( [RequestId] => c1da8997-2e32-50d0-a092-c45229f36fd7 ) ) ) )
```

Steps I followed:

1. Created google API credentials for GCM. Used projectid in app and Server key for Amazon platform
2. Created user in aws and added policies with all access for sns
3. Used amazon user credentials in php aws api
4. Created amazon sns application platform form Android/GCM and used google server key there.
5. Added Application ARN received from above steps to php api calls.
6. In php cron, created AmazonEndpoint for device using registration_id received from GCM.
7. Published notification message on amazon endpoint.
8. and stuck ......not receiving notification on device even after getting success status in api call

Can anyone tell me exact steps? Am i missing anything?

Comment: Use the facility to send a manual message on SNS Dashboard to make sure you SNS/GCM is set up right. Then try to debug one step up at a time from there. Or one step down, if that fails.

Comment: share your relevant code

Comment: what is the JSON data content exactly?
I use {"GCM": {"data":{"message":"blah blah"}}}

Answer (score 3):

I used Firabase and AWS SNS service for sending from php. I did it step by step according to this video tutorial https://youtu.be/iBTFLu30dSg (on russian but with English subtitles). It works well for me now and I successfully receive push notification from my php code on the mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

use a json to topic like:

```
{
  "default": "Msg test from sns",
  "GCM": "{\"data\":{\"id\":\"161223182046\",\"badge\":1,\"message\":\"Msg test from sns\",\"title\":\"test\",\"_event\":{\"created\":1482547772}}}"
}
```

For an endpoint quit default row:

```
{
  "GCM":"{\"data\":{\"id\":\"161223182046\",\"badge\":1,\"message\":\"Msg test from sns\",\"title\":\"test\",\"_event\":{\"created\":1482547772}}}"
}
```

Where `id` and `_event.created` rows are unique for each push.